# How can i control my admin panel with php code?

Tags: php

I am working in a website where i want to add, delete, update my database in according to my admin panel with php code. What is the basic start of beginning for control my panel?

Comment: a login screen is the most primary

Comment: You should look for a good tutorial that can explain you how to create a CRUD application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add authorisation by login and password. After success your script should save in session information about correct login (like e.g logged = true). Then you must to check if users have token in session - if so then show them admin panel, if not then redirect on login page